# Is there a way to get the current circulating supply of an asset via API?

Tags: native-assets, token, blockfrost, api

More specific, I am looking to fetch the circulating supply of native cardano tokens with the Blockfrost API. I know how to get the total supply, but I was wondering if there is any possibility to get the current circulating supply with a similar approach.

Comment: You can find out which addresses are used to store the amount not yet in circulation and subtract it from the total. I think there isn't much more behind the concept of "in circulation" than not being in the reserve wallet, vesting contract etc.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a solution. It's a nasty one for sure, but I think I'll give it a try.  
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Given the native assets cannot be staked, they are all in circulation.

Just fetch it with `/assets` and see the `quantity` field.

Comment: Nah, the problem is essentially that this would include tokens that are in some sort of treasury, and since these tokens are not really in circulation yet, it doesn't make sense to use them for calculations.

Comment: Tokens cannot be locked in the treasury (which uses account-based mode), only ADA can be.